# замена в частей текста в pandas

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, dataframe

можно такой код в две строчки написать?

```
df = pd.read_excel(way + r'1.xlsx', index = None)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], keep='last')
####################################
###ниже код, который хотелось бы сократить
####################################
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('*','.*')
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('?','.')
df[0] = df[0].replace(np.nan, '.*')
df[1] = df[1].str.replace('<>','')
df[1] = df[1].replace(np.nan, '.*')
```

и почему выдается такое предупреждение:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: укажите пожалуйста в вопросе как вы получили `df` - похоже что `df` - результат среза

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, проблему и приведите [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Если ответ ниже не помог, объясните, что именно работает не так.

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев, [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @MaxU, не совсем верно указано в коде. Там получается, что все из предложенных символов меняются на ".*", а меня несколько разных символов и условий

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев, можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
          0       1
0  sample1?  <tag1>
1       NaN  <tag2>
2  sample2*     NaN
```

решение:

```
In [19]: df[[0,1]] = df[[0,1]].fillna(".*")

In [20]: df[0] = df[0].replace([r"\*", r"\?"], [".*", "."], regex=True)

In [21]: df[1] = df[1].replace(r"[<>]", "", regex=True)
```

результат:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
           0     1
0   sample1.  tag1
1        ..*  tag2
2  sample2.*    .*
```